# Entity Framework Function Import with a Null Parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm implementing Entity Framework DB First in an ASP.NET application using Visual Studio 2010. In this Database there are many stored procedures like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PKG_EMPRESAS$BUSCAR] 
@PID_EMPRESA FLOAT(53) = NULL output
AS  
BEGIN  
    SELECT *  
      FROM EMPRESAS  
     WHERE ((@PID_EMPRESA IS NULL) OR (ID_EMPRESA = @PID_EMPRESA));  
END
```

When ever I try to call it in my .VB code:

```
Dim contexto As New ContextoGPI
Dim query = contexto.PKG_EMPRESAS_BUSCAR(Nothing)
query.GetEnumerator()
```

(Also tried with DBNULL.Value)

While debbuging I get an error in this code inside the `ModeloGPI.Designer.vb` of my `ModeloGPI.edmx`:

```
Public Function PKG_EMPRESAS_BUSCAR(pID_EMPRESA As ObjectParameter) As ObjectResult(Of EMPRESA)
   Return MyBase.ExecuteFunction(Of EMPRESA)("PKG_EMPRESAS_BUSCAR", pID_EMPRESA)
End Function
```

The Error Message:

> The parameter at index 0 in the parameters array is null

I can't find a way to specify in my Model that the parameter `@PID_EMPRESA` of de SP is nullable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What if you enter an `ObjectParameter` with value `null`?

Comment: You are correct, I found out that the OUTPUT in the SP is what's making this happen. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in the SP definition the nullable Parameter `PID_EMPRESA` is `OUTPUT`

When this happens Entity Framework sets it as an `ObjectParameter` instead of a Double because it returns a value.

So, before creating the query, just created an ObjectParameter with a `Value = DBNULL.Value`

```
Dim contexto As New ContextoGPI
Dim PARAM As New System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("pID_EMPRESA", DBNull.Value)

Dim query = contexto.PKG_EMPRESAS_BUSCAR(PARAM)
Dim resultado As IEnumerable
resultado = query.AsEnumerable
```

And that did the trick :P